# Внешний ip адрес в локальной сети?

Tags: сеть, ip, маршрутизация, роутер

Есть роутер:

Провайдер выделил мне внешний статический ip адрес:
48.39.242.122

Маска подсети:
255.255.255.0

Основной шлюз:
48.39.242.1

Это WAN

LAN ip роутера 
192.168.0.1

На роутере запущен автоматический DHCP сервер (192.168.0.60-192.168.0.200) и подключены некоторые узлы по mac адресам
192.168.0.101
192.168.0.102
192.168.0.103

Нужно чтобы на узле 
192.168.0.102 был еще доступен мой внешний ip 
48.39.242.122
чтобы настроить там DNS и WWW сервер

Как это можно организовать? Чтобы еще и функционировал DHCP сервер.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В роутере должен быть проброс портов (port forwarding или что-то в таком роде)

Comment: Такого не вижу в настройках. Есть  Port Triggering

Comment: «Переадресация» возможно оно

Comment: Добавил картинку

Comment: «Виртуальные серверы» возможно оно

Comment: А дальше str4n9er уже всё в ответе расписал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде есть такая интересная вещь, как DMZ, если туда прописать ваш локальный IP, то компьютер полностью будет торчать в интернете со всеми открытыми дырами.

Если вам нужен WWW сервер, то первым делом, желательно на роутере назначить статичный IP для локального компьютера, который работает как  веб-сервер. Затем через "Переадресация - Виртуальные серверы" перенаправить порты 80 и 443 (если надо) на назначенную статике. Не забыть проверить, что фаервол на локальном компьютере не блокирует ваш 80 и 443 порт.

Answer (score 2):

1. DHCP - Address Reservation. Зарезервировать ip-адрес 192.168.0.102 за определённым устройством.
2. Forwarding - Virtual Server - Add New. Тут добавить необходимы порты. 53 TCP/UDP для DNS и 80 TCP и 443 TCP для WEB.

Comment: Обычно адреса распределяют так: 192.168.0.1 - роутер, 192.168.0.2 - 192.168.0.9 - "сервера", 192.168.0.10 - 192.168.0.254 - DHCP